# insert data into table on checkbox check changed using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i want to insert data into table when checkbox is checked and delete data from table when check box is uncheked for that i a am using this ajax code.. is there any event that will fire when checkbox changed and checkbox uncheked

code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {


//$(".tb11").click(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.clUname', function(event)
{
//Save the link in a variable called element

var element = $(this);
var table = $('#selecttable').val();
//Find the id of the link that was clicked
var del_id = element.attr("id");

//Built a url to send
//var info = 'id=' + del_id,'&selecttable=' + table
 if(confirm("Are You Sure You Want Delete This Record."))
          {

 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "DeletePropertyGalleryData.php",
      data: 
            {
                id: del_id ,selecttable: table

            },
   success: function(){

   }
 });

 }

return false;

});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Search for checkbox events in google..

Comment: i searched but didnt get any solution

Comment: What you mean by `didnt get any solution`. Copy pasting the above comment gave me a dozen of results. See this https://www.google.co.in/search?q=checkbox+events&rlz=1C1AVNC_enIN561IN561&oq=checkbox+events&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=122&espv=210&newwindow=1&q=checkbox+events+jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with Onchange it also catch the checkbox event

```
$(document).on('change', '.clUname', function(event)
{

});
```

Comment: actually i was using click function thats why it was not working my check box cheked staus was not retaining ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `.clUname` is your checkbos, use:

```
$('.clUname').change(function(){
    // AJAX code here    
});
```

More info.: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox check, uncheck will call jQuery [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event.

If .clUname is checkbox class, then use following code :

```
jQuery('.clUname').change(function(){
     if(this.checked) {
         // Insert Data
     }else{
         // Delete Data
     }

})
```